# Rails 3 Devise Production Mode Issue Superclass Mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, production-environment

I have:
Rails 3.0.9
Devise 1.5.3

I'm using Devise for user authentication.
Everything goes perfect when I'm under development mode.
But when I try to switch Rails from development to production mode I get a message:

**C:/Sites/eFiling2/app/controllers/user_controller.rb:1:in 'top (required)': su
perclass mismatch for class User (TypeError)**

```
C:/Sites/eFiling2/app/controllers/user_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': su
perclass mismatch for class User (TypeError)
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:346:in `require_or_load'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:300:in `depend_on'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/e
ngine.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/e
ngine.rb:137:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/e
ngine.rb:137:in `block in eager_load!'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/e
ngine.rb:135:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/e
ngine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/a
pplication.rb:108:in `eager_load!'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/a
pplication/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/i
nitializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/i
nitializable.rb:25:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/i
nitializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/i
nitializable.rb:49:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/i
nitializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/a
pplication.rb:134:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/a
pplication.rb:77:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Sites/eFiling2/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/eFiling2/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/builde
r.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/builde
r.rb:46:in `initialize'
        from C:/Sites/eFiling2/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from C:/Sites/eFiling2/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/builde
r.rb:35:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/builde
r.rb:35:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/server
.rb:162:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/server
.rb:253:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.5/lib/rack/server
.rb:204:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/c
ommands/server.rb:65:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/c
ommands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/c
ommands.rb:27:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/c
ommands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

**user_controller.rb:**

```
class User < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

check your Gemfile and what are you requiring in `environment.rb` line 5

and at least remove `before_filter :authenticate_user!` from `user_controller` ..as you can't register new user if not already logged in

if you see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

there is

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create, :cancel ]
  prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

so if you add that before_filter, you broke all the functionality